# pyspark writing accented character in a dataframe

Tags: encoding, utf-8, pyspark, non-ascii-characters

I have a spark job that reads a file and then json parse line by a line and just read one the json key as an example

```
logs = sc.textFile(path_to_file)

# log['a_key'] contain UTF data (accented character)
logs = logs.map(lambda x: json.loads(x)).map(lambda x: x['a_key'])
df = sql_context.createDataFrame(logs, ["test_column"])
df.coalesce(1).write.format("com.databricks.spark.csv").options(header=True).save(destination_path)
```

When I look a the outpouted csv file all the accented character are replaced by strange character.

How do I make pyspark write accented character in the csv file ? I have tried using log['a_key'].encode('UTF-8') but it was the same result

Comment: First thing to find out is if the encoding actually went wrong, or if it's maybe the tool you use for opening the file that has the wrong idea of how the data are encoded. Specifically, MS Excel has a strong tendency to think that CSV files are in CP-1252 or something similar. In that case, for example, the character “á” correctly encoded with UTF-8 would be displayed as “'Ã¡'”.

Comment: I thought about this as well but I have 'cat' the file (before opening it in excel) and it is indeed not utf-8. 
"DÃ©couvrez la vie"
I have played a bit with pyspark command line and I am 100% sure now that the variables that are being written in the csv are unicode 

u'D\xe9couvrez la vie de ch\xe2teau'

Comment: This supports my point. It means that not only Excel, but also your terminal thinks that your file is Latin-1 or CP-1252, even though it is correctly encoded as UTF-8. The unicode strings you have look fine, too. You only need to change your command-line interpreter's encoding and specify UTF-8 when opening the file in Excel.

Comment: echo $LANG gives
en_GB.UTF-8

I can correctly cat other file where I know there is accented character and they appear correctly

Comment: What do you get for `file com.databricks.spark.csv`?

Comment: And is the "other file" with accented characters encoded in UTF-8? If your code is in Python 2, it's possible that the CSV file is double-encoded (encoded with UTF-8, then implicitly decoded with Latin-1 and again encoded with UTF-8).

Comment: To inspect what is actually written to disk, open the file in Python with 'b' mode. "Découvrez" should look like `D\xc3\xa9couvrez`.